# Generic components in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a quiz in Vue.js, quiz questions can be different types:

- Select one
- Select multiple
- Select image
- Match

My problem is that types of questions are mixed (e.g. you can have any of them in the quiz) and thus are different components (`<x-select-one-question>`, `<x-select-multiple-question>`, `<x-select-image-question>`, `<x-match>` etc) so I can't simply put one component into quiz.

How can, and should I make a generic component for this? Maybe something like this?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <x-question 
      v-for="(question, index) in questions" 
      :key="index" 
      type="question.type"></x-question>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'component' type then on run time set the relevante component with the attr 'is' like this:

```
<component :is="componentToRender(type)
```

In the function you will check witch component you want to return, like:

```
componentToRender(type){
 case 'quiz1': return 'QuizOneComponent';
// continue like this
}
```

Comment: I apologise for not questanot checkmarking this question

Answer (score 0):

Your component could be something like that

```
<template>
<select v-if="type == 'select'">
  <option v-for="item in items" value="item.value">{{ item.text }}</option>
</select>
<select v-else-if="type == 'multiple'" multiple>
  <option v-for="item in items" value="item.value">{{ item.text }}</option>
</select>
<input v-else-if="type == 'image'" type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
</template>

Vue.component('question', {
  template: '#question',
  props: {
    type: {
        default: ''
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: [
        { value: 1, text: 'One' },
        { value: 2, text: 'Two' },
        { value: 3, text: 'Three' }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

With that, you should be able to pass the correct **prop** like 'select', 'multiple' or 'image' to show the input you want.

```
<div id="app">
  <question type='image'></question>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct3s4z5n/11/) if you want to try by yourself.